# Is there a method of printing all lines matching a string (this part complete) and a set number of lines after that string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to extract relevant data of a traffic junction and it's connections from a log file. Example log:

```
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road                                
Modified                   By ________                                          
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1271      C           DD1271    R                                     
        DD1351      D           DD1351    B                                     
                    E                                                           
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
       Stage Suffix for Offset Optimizer  1                                     
Double Cycle Initially ?  N   Force Single / Double Cycling status ? N          
Double Cycle Group       00   Double Cycle Ignore ? N                           
Allow Link Max Saturation N   Link Max Sat Override N                           
Stages       1   2   3   4                                                      
Fixed        N   N   N   Y                                                      
LRT stage    N   N   N   N                                                      
Skip allowed N   N   N   N                                                      
Ped stage    N   N   N   N                                                      
Ped invite   N   N   N   N                                                      
Ghost stage  N   N   N   N                                                      
Offset authority pointer   0     Split authority pointer   0                    
Offset opt emiss weight  000     I/green feedback inhibit  N                    
                                                                                
                                                                                
Bus Authority   00  ACIS node  00000                                            
                                                                                
Bus Mode - Central extensions  N   Local extensions  N  Recalls  N              
           Stage skipping      N   Stage truncation  N Cancels   N              
Bus Priority Selection - Multiple buses  N  Queue Calculation  N                
Hold recall if faulty N  Disable recall  N  Disable long jtim  N  Real Cancel N 
                                                                                
Bus recall recovery type      0  Bus extension recovery type  0                 
Offset Bus authority pointer  0  Split Bus authority pointer  0                 
Bus skip recovery             0  Skip importance factor       0                 
Bus priority status   OFF                                                       
LRT sat 1  000  LRT sat 2  000  LRT sat 3  000                                  
                                                                                
                                                                                
                  PEDESTRIAN FACILITIES                                         
Ped Node                   N        Num Ped Wait Imp Factor     000             
Ped Priority               0        Max Ped Priority Freq        00             
Ped Lower Sat Threshold  000        Ped Upper Sat Threshold     000             
Max Ped Wait Time        000                                                    
               PEDESTRIAN VARIABLE INVITATION TO CROSS                          
Allow Ped Invite       N            Ped Priority Auto           000             
Ped Invite Upper Sat 000 Prio Level 1    2    3    4                            
Max Ped Priority Smoothed Time     000  000  000  000                           
Max Ped Priority Increase Length    00   00   00   00                           
                  CYCLE TIME FACILITIES                                         
Allow Node Independence    N        Operator Node Independence    0             
Ghost Demand Stage         N        Num Ghost Assessment Cycles  15             
Upper Trigger Ghost       04        Lower Trigger Ghost           0             
                                                                                
SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street                                  
Modified 13-OCT-15 15:06   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1301      T           DD1301    A                                     
        DD1251      R           DD1251    C                                     
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
       Stage Suffix for Offset Optimizer  1                                     
Double Cycle Initially ?  N   Force Single / Double Cycling status ? N          
Double Cycle Group       00   Double Cycle Ignore ? N                           
Allow Link Max Saturation N   Link Max Sat Override N                           
Stages       1   2   3                                                          
Fixed        N   Y   Y                                                          
LRT stage    N   N   N                                                          
Skip allowed N   N   N                                                          
Ped stage    N   N   N                                                          
Ped invite   N   N   N                                                          
Ghost stage  N   N   N                                                          
Offset authority pointer   0     Split authority pointer   0                    
Offset opt emiss weight  000     I/green feedback inhibit  N                    
                                                                                
                                                                                
Bus Authority   00  ACIS node  00000                                            
                                                                                
Bus Mode - Central extensions  N   Local extensions  N  Recalls  N              
           Stage skipping      N   Stage truncation  N Cancels   N              
Bus Priority Selection - Multiple buses  N  Queue Calculation  N                
Hold recall if faulty N  Disable recall  N  Disable long jtim  N  Real Cancel N 
                                                                                
Bus recall recovery type      0  Bus extension recovery type  0                 
Offset Bus authority pointer  0  Split Bus authority pointer  0                 
Bus skip recovery             0  Skip importance factor       0                 
Bus priority status   OFF                                                       
LRT sat 1  000  LRT sat 2  000  LRT sat 3  000                                  
                                                                                
                                                                                
                  PEDESTRIAN FACILITIES                                         
Ped Node                   N        Num Ped Wait Imp Factor     000             
Ped Priority               0        Max Ped Priority Freq        00             
Ped Lower Sat Threshold  000        Ped Upper Sat Threshold     000             
Max Ped Wait Time        000                                                    
               PEDESTRIAN VARIABLE INVITATION TO CROSS                          
Allow Ped Invite       N            Ped Priority Auto           000             
Ped Invite Upper Sat 000 Prio Level 1    2    3    4                            
Max Ped Priority Smoothed Time     000  000  000  000                           
Max Ped Priority Increase Length    00   00   00   00                           
                  CYCLE TIME FACILITIES                                         
Allow Node Independence    N        Operator Node Independence    0             
Ghost Demand Stage         N        Num Ghost Assessment Cycles  15             
Upper Trigger Ghost       04        Lower Trigger Ghost           0
```

I can already extract the first relevant line using the following Bash script:

```
grep SCN* LOG.TXT > JUNCTIONS.txt
```

Which creates a list of all the junctions like so:

```
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road                                
SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street                                  
SCN DD1301       At Glasgow Road - Argyll Road - Cart Street                    
SCN DD1351       At Kilbowie Road - Chalmers Street
...
```

However, I want to extract the lines immediately after each link title, down to the final link of the node just before a large amount of whitespace and without capturing anything from Stage Suffix onwards until the next link.

Is there a way to modify my BASH script to include an additional number of lines after each matching instance it finds?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want `sed -n -e '/SCN/,/^\s*$/p'`

which will print all lines between the line matching /SCN/ and the first line that is all whitespace.

If you have a fixed number of lines you want to match and have the appropriate grep, you might also try:

`grep -A 9 SCN`

which prints lines that match SCN and the 9 lines after a match.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl` you can print the matching sections like this:

```
perl -ne 'print if(/^SCN / .. /^\s*$/);' LOG.TXT
```

- `-n` assume `while (<>) { ... }` loop around program
- `-e <program>` (the code to execute)
- `print` each line from a line starting with `SCN`  until a line with only whitespace characters (zero or more) is encountered.

This will be repeated for all `SCN` sections in `LOG.TXT` and would produce the following output from your example:

```
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road
Modified                   By ________
Type CR
Region  WS  Subregion
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK
        DD1271      C           DD1271    R
        DD1351      D           DD1351    B
                    E

SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street
Modified 13-OCT-15 15:06   By BDAVIDSON
Type CR
Region  WS  Subregion
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK
        DD1301      T           DD1301    A
        DD1251      R           DD1251    C
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `awk` (very similar to William's `sed` solution):

```
$ awk '/SCN/,/^\s*$/' LOG.TXT 
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road                                
Modified                   By ________                                          
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1271      C           DD1271    R                                     
        DD1351      D           DD1351    B                                     
                    E                                                           
                                                                                
SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street                                  
Modified 13-OCT-15 15:06   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1301      T           DD1301    A                                     
        DD1251      R           DD1251    C
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity. I don't think this is a script, is a pipeline.

```
grep SCN* LOG.TXT > JUNCTIONS.txt
```

But you have run the grep with two options:
Like this:

```
grep -A2 -B2 SCN
```

A = After
B = Before.

To script, you can run a file, like script.sh with +x ACL.
like this:

`$chmod +x script.sh`

```
 #!/bin/env bash 
    var=$1
    m=$2
    n=$3
    grep -A $m -B $n $1 >somefile
```

then run follow command:

```
bash script.sh SCN 2 2
```